# C++ Program crashes when I use a big number

Tags: c++, crash

I am very new to c++, so i don't know a lot, just the very basics. I tried to write a program to find a number's largest prime factor. It works great for 5 digit numbers, but the program crashes when i enter a number greater than 5 digits. I actually needed to use the program for a 12 digit number. Can anyone please suggest what should i change in the code. The code is as follows

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool checkPrime(uint64_t a, uint64_t x)
{
    a = a + 1;
    uint64_t b = a*a;
    if (b <= x)
    {
        if (x%a == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            checkPrime(a, x);
        }
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}

uint64_t  findPrime(uint64_t a, uint64_t x, uint64_t h)
{
    a = a+1;
    if (a <= x)
    {
        if (x%a == 0)
        {
            if (checkPrime(1, a))
            {
                h = a;
                findPrime(a, x, h);
            }
            else
            {
                h = h;
                findPrime(a, x, h);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            h = h;
            findPrime(a, x, h);
        }
    }
    else {
        return h;
    }
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    uint64_t f;
    cout << "Enter the Number: ";
    cin >> f;
    uint64_t z = findPrime(1, f, 1);
    cout << "Largest Prime Factor is " << z << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The recursion gets too deep. Rewrite using loops.

Comment: And recursive functions should return the results of the recursive calls.

Comment: Did you perform any debugging at all?

Answer (score 0):

I would start by adding a simple cout statement at several places inside each function to determine where your error is occurring.

It could be, as molbdnile indicated, that your recursion goes too deep. It may be better to rewrite it as a forloop using *a* as your counter.

Another potential problem is

```
uint64_t b = a*a;
```

If *a* was large enough multiplying it to itself could overflow *b*

Comment: thanks a lot, i take a tutorial in loops as i haven't until now. And i would use the cout suggestion, it helped a lot.